# Solving for a possible angle for a trigonometric equation of power 5

Tags: trigonometry

Find a possible angle x for which-
$$243+\frac{135}{2\sin^2 x}+\frac{15}{16\sin^4x}=\frac{405}{2\sin x}+\frac{45}{4\sin^3x}+\frac{1}{32\sin^5 x}$$

I have no idea how to do this question after an hour. I’ve tried substitution but I can’t solve a degree 5 polynomial. The numbers does seem to have a pattern (for e.g, $135+45=180$ and $405-45=360$) but that’s it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint…substitute $u=\frac{1}{2\sin x}$ and notice that:
$$3^5=243$$
$$3\times 45=135$$ and $$15\times 3^3=405$$
So you can deduce a solution…